# jQuery slider up/down + Twitter widget conflict?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter, widget

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PBmq/2/) code that works fine if no [Twitter widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile/) was inserted yet. What it does is slides down and up the content (upon clicking on the link "click here").

But, once I insert a default code from [get a Twitter widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile/) in [there](http://jsfiddle.net/7PBmq/3/) (see the html part, that's the only part that was changed, Twitter code was added), it doesn't work, it doesn't slide down.

Why it does not slide down when the Twitter widget added, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Welp, this looks good to me](http://jsfiddle.net/7PBmq/4/).

I don't know...I just moved the scripts around, added resources properly, and added an empty div called `<div id="twitterbox">`

Then in your new TWTR script, I targeted the element that I wanted the twitter feed to load into

```
id: 'twitterbox'
```

then I ran the jsFiddle and it worked fine. Perhaps that's what you were missing?